# How to get WHERE statement to return a result for each unique ID?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get the most recent ACQUISITIONFACTOR for each subscriber ID from the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Exercise 
(
    SubscriberID int,
    StatementDate DATE,
    AcquisitionFactor DECIMAL(4, 2)
);

INSERT INTO Exercise VALUES (1, DATE '2005-03-15', 80.0);
INSERT INTO Exercise VALUES (1, DATE '2005-04-15', 0.90);
INSERT INTO Exercise VALUES (1, DATE '2005-05-15', 0.90);
INSERT INTO Exercise VALUES (1, DATE '2005-06-15', 0.90);
INSERT INTO Exercise VALUES (2, DATE '2017-08-15', 66.7);
INSERT INTO Exercise VALUES (2, DATE '2017-09-15', 66.7);
INSERT INTO Exercise VALUES (2, DATE '2017-10-15', 0.50);
INSERT INTO Exercise VALUES (3, DATE '2017-10-15', 0.66);
INSERT INTO Exercise VALUES (4, DATE '2017-10-15', 0.55);
```

| SUBSCRIBERID | STATEMENTDATE | ACQUISITIONFACTOR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15-MAR-05 | 80 |
| 1 | 15-APR-05 | .9 |
| 1 | 15-MAY-05 | .9 |
| 1 | 15-JUN-05 | .9 |
| 2 | 15-AUG-17 | 66.7 |
| 2 | 15-SEP-17 | 66.7 |
| 2 | 15-OCT-17 | .5 |
| 3 | 15-OCT-17 | .66 |
| 4 | 15-OCT-17 | .55 |

This is the query that I've come up with.

```
SELECT 
    SubscriberID, AcquisitionFactor 
FROM 
    Exercise 
WHERE 
    StatementDate = (SELECT MAX(StatementDate) FROM Exercise);
```

| SUBSCRIBERID | ACQUISITIONFACTOR |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | .5 |
| 3 | .66 |
| 4 | .55 |

The problem is that it only returns results from SUBSCRIBERID 2 - 4. How do I get it to return the `AcquisitionFactor` for all 4 IDs? Thanks!

Comment: I'd try something like `SELECT e1.subid, e1.date, e1.factor FROM Excercise e1 JOIN (SELECT subid, MAX(date) as date FROM Excercise GROUP BY subid) e2 ON e1.subid = e2.subid AND e1.date = e2.date` – might need fixes in some details...

Answer (score 1):

You are close with your solution, but you need to correlate that subquery by providing a relationship between your main query and your subquery in your subquery's WHERE clause.

```
SELECT SubscriberID, AcquisitionFactor 
FROM Exercise e1
WHERE StatementDate=(SELECT max(StatementDate) FROM Exercise e2 WHERE e1.SubscriberID = e2.SubscriberID);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the aggregate `max` function with [the `last` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/LAST.html#GUID-4E16BC0E-D3B8-4BA4-8F97-3A08891A85CC):

```
SELECT SubscriberID,
  MAX(AcquisitionFactor) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY StatementDate) AS AcquisitionFactor
FROM Exercise
GROUP BY SubscriberID;
```

| SUBSCRIBERID | ACQUISITIONFACTOR |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | .9 |
| 2 | .5 |
| 3 | .66 |
| 4 | .55 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=647b56f232088c9af2b5b307a3788359)

It's trivial to then include the date as well if you want that - included as a final query in that fiddle.